# Error in github because of Clone and Fork

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-for-windows

I wanted to ask you that I did changes in my cloned repository in my local system but I forgot to fork it with my local user account.
My origin of a repository is  http://github.com/repository instead of http://github.com/useraccount/repository.
My question is, Is it possible to change the origin or get a fork to the cloned repository because When I push my changes to Github I am having an error:

"Unable to access 'https://github.com/repository/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

Comment: You could still fork it on github, then set a new remote to be that new forked repo. Then you can push like normal

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url), just set

```
git remote set-url origin http://github.com/useraccount/repository
```

Comment: Glad for having been helpful. You can now accept my answer.